# Facebook login for iOS - Only admin can login but other user not can

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, permissions

I have a new account and register a new developer APP. This app only use the 3 permissitons `@[@"public_profile", @"user_birthday", @"user_friends"]`. But currently App can only be login  by admin account but other user account can't login.

I set some user account to 'tester' and 'developer' item in admin account, but these accounts still can't login. How do i do now?
[Setting as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6C2Z.png)

Comment: Your status and review settings is on? i think your app is not on?

Comment: r u enabled your app is public..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not enable your app is public.. if yes go to

**Step1:** open the [url](https://developers.facebook.com/)

**Step2:** select your app and open your app and select **settings** button

**Step3:**: add your mail id on **Contact Email** fields and click **Save changes**

[image]

**Step4:**: select the **Status & review** button and change your app to global,just like

[image]

done !!!

Comment: You’re Wonderful. I can login by other user account now except for there hasn't return 'birthday'.

Comment: it birthday also depricated

Comment: Hello. I follow your guide but I still cannot login. why?

Comment: Hello. I also did that but cannot login. Do you know why?